# Using Amazon RDS for GeoDjango?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, geodjango

I want to run my site on a EC2 instance, using RDS for the Postgres database. It supports PostGIS, but when I try to run the migrate command I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database "mydb". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database template?
```

There isn't a postgis template database. The scripts I normally use to create the template produce tons of errors, most likely because I'm running postgres 9.1 and AWS uses 9.3. Before I try upgrading to 9.3 and pulling my hair out after that doesn't work smoothly because nothing ever does, is there something I'm missing here?

Has anyone gotten GeoDjango running on an RDS database?

Comment: `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` ?

Comment: That totally worked, makes me wonder why the solutions I found for setting up the database before involved running a couple lengthy SQL scripts.

Comment: Because old PostGIS versions from before PostgreSQl had extension support needed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to create the extension manually:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Comment: I have the same problem even after creating all the required extensions… any idea?

Comment: Django still attempts to install the extension and will throw an error.

Comment: Are you sure you created it in the same database as Django is using?